# R squared change multiple linear regression

Tags: r, multiple-regression, r-squared

I calculate multiple linear regression in R with

```
lm(var ~ VAR1+VAR2+VAR3+VAR4)
```

Do you know how to calculate R-squared change for each variable `VAR1`, `VAR2`, `VAR3` ?
Thank you

Comment: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Partial-R-square-in-multiple-linear-regression-td4632130.html

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean here? Eg, what do you want to do w/ this information when you get it? Are you wondering how to conduct the R-squared change *test*? Do you want to know the variance in `var` marginally associated w/ each `VAR`, or partially associated? etc.

Comment: I want to get the contribution of each variables VAR1, VAR2, VAR3, etc to explain var.

Answer (score 2):

The OP essentially wants to calculate the $R^2$ differences for individual variables. So the models would be:

```
m0 = lm(var ~ VAR1 + VAR2 + VAR3)
m1 = lm(var ~ VAR2 + VAR3)
m2 = lm(var ~ VAR1 + VAR3)
m3 = lm(var ~ VAR1 + VAR2)
```

And then you can do

```
pr2m1 = summary(m0)$r.squared-summary(m1)$r.squared
pr2m2 = summary(m0)$r.squared-summary(m2)$r.squared
pr2m3 = summary(m0)$r.squared-summary(m3)$r.squared
```

But this probably doesn't do what you think it does (explain exactly how much the individual variables explain via the $R^2$ difference) - at least if there is any multicollinearity (which there usually is).

Comment: `summary(m0)$r.squared` works for me, not name subscripting...

Answer (score 0):

Why not computing all the nested models ?

```
lm(var ~ VAR1)
lm(var ~ VAR1 + VAR2)
lm(var ~VAR1 + VAR2 + VAR3)
```